# facing an obstacle in Fixtures creation in the Simpletest

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp-1.3, simpletest

I am beginner to Simpletest and facing an issue while creating fixtures. As I am using cakephp 1.3.14 version for my application.

1. Created fixture with filename complaint_fixture.php

   ```
   class ComplaintFixture extends CakeTestFixture {

       var $name = 'Complaint';
       var $import = array('table' => 'complaints', 'records' => true);

       // do not truncate movie_stars table between tests
       public function truncate($db) {
           return null;
       }

       // do not drop movie_stars table between tests
       public function drop($db) {
           return null;
       }

   }
   ```
2. Created test case with name complaint.test.php

   ```
   App::import('Model', 'Complaint');

   class ComplaintTestCase extends CakeTestCase {

       var $fixtures = array('app.Complaint');

       function setUp($method) {
           parent::setUp();
           $this->Complaint = & ClassRegistry::init('Complaint');

           // load data
           $this->loadFixtures('Complaint');
       }

       function testFixture() {
           $numberOfResults = $this->Complaint->find('count');
           var_dump($numberOfResults);
       }

       /*
         function testupdateComplaintStatus(){
         $result = $this->Complaint->updateComplaintStatus(47,'ACT');
         $this->assertEqual($result,1,'Status updated successfully!');
         } */
   }
   ```

As you can see in the above code, a fixture is created with name Complaint and then a test case is being used to load that fixture. So, what I have read on it from developer guide
- we do create a fixture with specifying the fields name and a records set
- load that fixture in test model class.

**BUT, what I am looking for is to perform CRUD operations on test data which is being inserted into the test database. And, when I try to do the same with above given script, It starts affecting the production database records instead of test database.**

If you see in the above code I have even stopped *truncate* and *drop* for test data, yet not able to sort out the issue.

Can anyone let me know what I have missed in the above code?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is your problem, but what if you try moving the init of Complaint into a startCase (in your Test Case), and get rid of the setUp method completely, including the parent::setUp() and $this->loadFixtures('Complaint')? That's how I have mine set up and it's working fine.

Comment: This is just an instance of model test case, I am having multiple test cases to execute in the model file that is the reason of loading the fixture inside setUp() function. Anyways, that is not my problem. Please read my question carefully.